# Potential of a non-uniformly charged spherical shell

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, potential

This question is taken from The Feynman Lectures on electromagnetism.

> A spherical shell with surface charge density $\sigma = \sigma_0 \cos \theta$ is given. The potential at any external point is needed. The book states that this can be considered to be the potential of a dipole formed by the superposition of two uniformly charged spheres slightly displaced relative to each other. This method will not involve any integral.

I do not really understand how to proceed after this point. For the dipole moment I need the charge. 
So I took $$\rm{d} A = 2 \pi a^2 \sin \theta \rm{d}\theta,$$
  and,   $$q = \int 2 \sigma_0 \pi a^2 \sin \theta \cos \theta \rm{d} \theta$$  with limits from $0$ to $\pi/2$ to get the total positive charge. This gives me $q =  \sigma_0 \pi a^2$.
Thus, $p = \sigma_0 \pi a^2 \Delta $, where $Δ$ is the small displacement between the spheres.
But, the dipole moment is given to be $4/3 \cdot \pi a^3 \sigma_0$.
Could anyone guide me?

Answer (score 1):

Consider first a charged sphere of radius $a$ with a uniform density $\rho=\sigma_0/d$. Since $\sigma_0$ is surface density, one has to divide by a length to get a volume density. Write the potentiel outside the sphere ($r>a$):
   $$\varphi(r)={4\over 3}\pi a^3\rho {1\over 4\pi\varepsilon_0r}$$
Now consider two spheres with uniform charge densities $\rho=\pm \sigma_0/d$ respectively whose centers are located at $\vec r_\pm=\pm {d\over 2}\vec u_z$. Write the total potential
   $$\varphi(r)={a^3\sigma_0/d\over 3\varepsilon_0}
   \left[{1\over ||\vec r-d/2\vec u_z||}-{1\over ||\vec r+d/2\vec u_z||}
\right]$$
Perform a Taylor expansion to lowest order (same calculation as the dipole).

The last step is to convince yourself that the two spheres are equivalent to a single sphere with a surface density $\sigma_0\cos\theta$ (draw a figure for example). When you substract the two spheres, you end up with a thin spherical layer whose thickness is $d\cos\theta$. Consider a surface element $dS$ on this layer. The charge carried is $\rho dV=\sigma_0/d\times dS\times d\cos\theta=\sigma_0\cos\theta dS$. Therefore, it can be interpreted as a sphere carrying a surface density $\sigma=\sigma_0\cos\theta$.

Comment: Thanks. I understood what you wrote but why are we taking the volume charge density as σ₀/d instead of 3σ₀/a as would come by equating charges ?

Comment: Because only the choice $\rho=\sigma_0/d$ leads to $\sigma=\sigma_0\cos\theta$. See the new paragraph at the end of my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I did everything right, only I couldn't get the relation between σ and ρ. I understood what you wrote. Thanks a lot.